# Is there a way to add x , y, z coordinate to the attribute table of polygon in ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have a large No. of converted DXF files, that represent the pitched roof. I want to calculate the roof area for each single building (that may consist of 4 to 10 polygon). The adjacent polygon must be identified, for that I need a x,y,z for each set of points to specified polygon.

Comment: It is unclear, do you already have a points to which you want to add theirs x,y,z values? or do you want to create points on polygons borders and than compute x,y,z?
A wider review of the data you actually have might help to understand how can you calculate the roof area of ach building...

Comment: Are your data is georeferenced? please clear it.

Comment: more precisely I want to identify the x,y,z for all corners of the polygon. The reason for that I want to calculate the roof area, that may consist of different numbers of polygons. 
Yes the data is georeferenced.

Comment: @dof1985 more precisely I want to identify the x,y,z for all corners of the polygon. The reason for that I want to calculate the roof area, that may consist of different numbers of polygons

Comment: Welcome to GSE. Please *edit* the question to resolve issues raised by comments. You don’t need to leave the same response twice, once for each comment (and this in fact adds to the importance of editing the question). Please also address why the polygon can't simply be queried for its area.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to calculate just the x,y,z centroid of the polygon, then you can add columns and calculate the geometry of the polygons. This is done in the attribute table by right clicking on the field and choosing Calculate Geometry.

[image]

[image]

However, if you want to get the x,y,z of each node of the building, you will need to export the nodes to points, and then you can do the same process as stated above. Let it be known that you can calculate the area for each polygon with this process.

Comment: thanks, that is true but I cannot relate all those polygon to the each building. The main reason to calculate building envelops area (facade and Walls) and Building volume for every building at city scale. So I need to have the xyz for the nodes of each polygon then I will regroup them (relate them to building ID) by python Code. This I will identify the adjacent line between each polygon. see below

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding your issue. According to your comment, you need the x,y,z centroid of the polygon. The process described above will provide you what you need. I would suggest that you edit your post to clarify your requirements, as well as provide a screen shot of our issue, so that others can visualize what you are asking.

Comment: !<a href="http://imgur.com/GTLWhhj"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/GTLWhhj.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>

Comment: ![link](http://i.imgur.com/GTLWhhj.png).      Kindly see the link.

Comment: Looks like you need dissolve the neighbouring polygons first

Comment: It is exactly why I need the coordinate of the nods, so that I identify the group of polygons to the specific building. I have developed an algorithm but it needs the coordinates as inputs. Any suggestion?

Comment: Then you need to export the nodes as points, then calculate the x,y,z. If you have a unique ID for each polygon, that ID will come over when you export/convert the nodes to points. With that, you can relate the nodes x,y,z back to the polygons. Really there isn't any other way.